# How close to roof should downspout be?

Tags: roof, gutters, rain, downspout

I know it is common for 2nd story gutters to empty on the roof surface; however, houses I've seen the gutter empty close to the roof.  my recently install gutters seem to be four to five inches off the roof.  Is there such a thing as too high?

[image: Right side]
[image: Left side]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing the answer is "no", but let's see what our pros say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I don’t know of a code related height I might slip a flat piece of galvanized flashing under the upper shingle so the water hitting the shingle hits the flashing then runs down without adding a section of downspout that may not look so nice. A dollop of silicone or roofing patch like black jack brand roof patch would hold it in place without needing a nail. I don’t have any interest in black jack brand I have used it throughout my career .

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the downspout with another section and put another elbow on it  so it dumps directly into the lower gutter.

That would eliminate the water wearing the roof prematurely or the need to alter the roof.

Answer (score 0):

Any unusual wear on a roof will eventually “show” differently. Depending on the size of the upper roof, you could have a substantial amount of water splashing onto the lower roof.

Water will create a “wash” on the granules. That is to say, water running over the shingles will wash more granules off than where just the rain hits the roof.

We use a 10”x18” “splash pan” made of stainless steel with its edges turned up 2” on 3 sides. It is then installed with mastic under the downspout opening. It will protect the shingles directly under the downspout opening and allow the rain water to spread out before running down the lower shingles.